# How to calculate percentages in LESS CSS?

Tags: css, operators, less

I would like to calculate the width of child-container (div etc) in percentages depending on the parent container with [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org).

I am using the forumula by Ethan Marcotte: *target / context = result*.

Parent container: 620px

Child container: 140px

I am using this calculation:

```
div.child-container {
    width: (140/620)*100%;
}
```

However the output is:

```
div.child-container {
    width: 0.2258064516129;
}
```

I would like to move the decimal point two digits and add the %, like this:

```
div.child-container {
    width: 22.58064516129%;
}
```

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: `100% == 1`, so the math makes sense.

Comment: The output is looking right for me given your input.

Comment: @zzzzBov

Thanks, I tried using *10000% in order to move the decial point and it works, but somehow the % sign is removed each time. 
The bottom sample is what I need as parsed output though.

Comment: My experience with LESS CSS is just looking up information related to this question, so I'm going to go out on a limb and say you need it to say `width: 100%*(140/620);` because I read that it picks the units off of the first value in the equation.

Comment: @Hexxagonal is right - the output is correct, you are probably using an old or nonstandard version of the LESS parser. How are you parsing your LESS? Less.JS newer versions should do it right.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to the [LESS CSS website](http://lesscss.org/#operations), you need to change the order of your equation

> The output is pretty much what you expect—LESS understands the difference between colors and units. If a unit is used in an operation, like in:
>
> ```
> @var: 1px + 5;
> ```
>
> LESS will use that unit for the final output—`6px` in this case.

It should be:

```
width: 100%*(140/620);
```

Answer (score 27):

Maybe the [`percentage`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions-percentage) function didn't exist when OP was asking but for future reference I add this answer.

```
div.child-container {
    width: percentage(140/620);
}
```

Comment: Just for information. I tried 
`percentage((@index / 10) - 0.01);`
and it didn't work I had to add more parenthesis
`percentage(((@index / 10) - 0.01));`

I'm telling because maybe someone wants to do more "difficult" maths as I did, not just a division.

Comment: I think this is a lot cleaner than the OP's selected answer. Both work, but this is a lot more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2022, LESS 4.0 and division operator concerned:

> From 4.0, No division is performed outside of parens using / operator.

> ```
> @color: #222 / 2; // results in `#222 / 2`, not #111 (!)
> background-color: (#FFFFFF / 16); //results is #101010
> ```

See the [docs](https://lesscss.org/#operations).