# Font percentage ratio

Tags: html, css

Found this piece of code in a stylesheet:

```
.dropcap
{
    float:left;
    font:normal 290%/85%;   
    line-height:90%;
    padding-right:0.02em;
    margin-bottom:-0.1em;
}
```

Could someone tell me what the percentages (290% and 85%) stand for? I thought 85% was the line height, but I'm obviously wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, helped me understand the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 290% should be the `font-size`, and you're right, the 85% should be `line-height`, however, that `font` shorthand declaration is incomplete: it should do **nothing**. You need to set a `font-family` in the `font` shorthand for it to be a valid property value.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Yh3g/

```
font:normal 290%/85% 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
```

**EDIT:** no, even if it is pre-processed code, it's still an invalid property value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pure CSS.  You're probably using LESS or similar, which can do math.

See also:  [How to calculate percentages in LESS CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8762225/362536)

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong, but the statement isn't complete, you have to specify the font-family too.

The line after that line sets the line-height to 90%, though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax

```
/* Set the font size to 12px and the line height to 14px. Set the font family to sans-serif */
p { font: 12px/14px sans-serif }
```