# Percentage of a value in less css

Tags: css, math, less, percentage

```
@x : 1000px;

width: @x - 20%;
```

So value should be 800, but instead it's 980 :|

Anyone know why

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762225/how-to-calculate-percentages-in-less-css ---- does this helps ?

Comment: `width: @x * .8;` where `.8` is obviously `(100-20)/100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following

```
width: @x - (@x/5);
```

Or for any particular percentage:

```
width: @x - ((@x/100)*(100-20));
```